# Transform an array from index to value sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an `int[] values` which has every time diffenent size of numbers. It's form is something  like that:

```
Index: 1 2 3 4 5
Value: 3 5 1 2 4
```

I want to tranform this array and return a new `int[]` which is sorted by value:

```
Index: 3 4 1 5 2
Value: 1 2 3 4 5
```

In other words i want to change the sorting and return a new `int[]` sorted by value, not by index.
How can i do that ?

An one-d array which indicates the index sorted by value can do the work, for example if the int [] values is something like that 400 500 232 123 999 the new int [] will be 
3 2 0 1 4

Comment: so you want to sort the array?

Comment: Why so complicated ?? You need  array  sorting?

Comment: Do you want to keep the original index for the values?

Comment: Do you mean you want to preserve the indicies like that? If so, you shouldn't be using an array, at least not a one dimensional array.

Comment: i don't want a 2-d to be returned.A one-d array which indicates the index sorted by value can do the work, for example if the int [] values is something like that 400 500 232 123 999 the new int [] will be 3 2 0 1 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int size=values.length;
    int [] SortedbyValue=new int [size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        SortedbyValue[values[i]]=i;
    }
    return SortedbyValue;
```

That's the answer i came up with...The above didn't help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
Arrays.sort(values);
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29) for more information

If you want to copy the values to a new array and sort that array, there are a few ways you can do it, this should suffice:

```
int[] sortedValues = new int[values.length];
System.arraycopy( values, 0, sortedValues, 0, values.length );
Arrays.sort(sortedValues);
```

Comment: Or in one line for the copy : `int[] sortedValues = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);`